# how can i recieve a file sent by an applet to the server by post method?

Tags: php

how can i receive a file sent by an applet to the server by an applet to the server by post method when on server i need a php file to receive it how can i do so?

i tried this;

```
<?php
$img_data = $_POST['txt'];
$fp = fopen('test.doc', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $img_data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Isn’t there one “by an applet to the server” too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [PHP manual on handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). There's a full example there (Example #2) that should get you started well.